# HBA card status

Tags: powershell, hba

Is it possible somehow to get status of a HBA card using PowerShell or any other API instead of logging to a server and run "powermt display path"?

Comment: Which make/model of HBA?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **[PowerShell Remoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/10/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart.aspx)** to run the command on remote machines.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and execute it remotely. You can even [wrap it in PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/2428.aspx) to run against a host of machines.

Comment: You don't need to wrap it in Powershell. PsExec can address multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

There can be quite a bit of data within wmi about hba\san info.  the following commands can lead you down the path.

gwmi -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" |   Select Name
gwmi -namespace "root\wmi" -list

if you use the -comp paramter it can be used against remote servers.

search on hba or lun.

bettter yet consulting with the manufacture might give you some insight as to whats doable.
another link to stuff is http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/storage/FCTopology.mspx

good luck